# Is "He has/owns many businesses" correct?

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, uncountable-nouns

Business is an uncountable noun,so shouldn't much be used in place of many?
Is this correct or not "He has/owns many businesses"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Why do you think *business* is exclusively uncountable?

Comment: I think I read about it in wren & martin. It isn't so, is it?

Answer (score 1):

***[Business](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/business)*** can be an uncountable noun, when referring to the activity in general. But it can also be a countable noun, when referring to a specific instance, like a corporation or a single-proprietorship.

"He has/owns many businesses" would be correct if using the second sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper dictionary, which indicates whether a noun is countable or uncountable, e.g.,

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/business

As you can see, some of the meanings there are listed as countable, some as uncountable.

Yours is 2:

> **busi‧ness**
>
> 2
>
> company
>
> **[countable]**   an organization such as a company, shop, or factory that produces or sells goods or provides a service